# Handle JSON response with multiple type of the same name

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

The JSON response is :

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errorMessages": [
        "You have to select a maximum load of <span style='color:red;'>0</span> Credit/Course but you have selected <span style='color:red;'>3</span> Credit/Course --- [R060]",
        "You can register courses as a full study with a load limit between <span style='color:red;'>12</span> and <span style='color:red;'>18</span> Credit/Course, but you have selected <span style='color:red;'>9</span> Credit/Course --- [R062]"
    ],
    "isConflict": 0
}
```

but when `isConflict == 1` the response is:

```
{
    "ignoreConflictValue": "W",
    "isConflict": 1,
    "conflict": [
        {
            "EXAM_DATE": "01/01/2019",
            "START_TIME": "08:00 AM",
            "END_TIME": "09:30 AM",
            "COURSE_NAME_SL": "مقاومة مواد,تقنيات الحفر البحري",
            "COURSE_NAME_PL": "STRENGTH OF MATERIALS,OFFSHORE TECHNOLOGY",
            "COURSES_COUNT": "2",
            "ACTIVE": "A"
        }
    ],
    "success": false
}
```

The logic of this API is :

- when `isConflict == 1` the success property is type of `Integer` with values 1 and 0.
- Otherwise the success property is type of `Boolean` with values `true` and `false`

My question is how to define the POJO class for this situation.

I tried to make two fields with the same name with `@Nullable` for both but `Gson` complains that the POJO has duplicate fields.

Comment: why would there be 2 properties that represent the same information. Also why would you create a POJO with 2 fields with the same name if there are no such fields in the json

Comment: I don't know, the type must be the same across all cases, but I can't change the API.

Comment: my 2nd question is more important

Comment: You may declare "success" variable of generic type "object" in your pojo and then using instance of to understand if it's a Boolean or an Integer

Comment: ^ don't do that

Comment: @TimCastelijns why not?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I doesn't work and return an exception that Gson excpecting OBJECT and received a NUMBER

Comment: @TimCastelijns I edited my question I need to define 2 fields to handle when `isConflict == 1` and `isConflict == 0` because every case return a different type but with the same name

Comment: use conflict list, if data is not there it will provide array list null..
SerializedName("isConflict")
Expose
private long isConflict;
SerializedName("conflict")
Expose
private List<Conflict> conflict = null;

Comment: Thank you so much It's worked

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can do the following:

Define "ApiResponse" class with generics like below:

```java
class ApiResponse(@SerializedName("success") val success : Any,
                  @SerializedName("errorMessages") val errorMessages : Array<Any>,
                  @SerializedName("isConflict")
                  val isConflict : Integer)
```

Then, in your activity, use Gson to convert the response with

```kotlin
 var responseOne = Gson().fromJson(textConflictOneResponse, ApiResponse::class.java)
        var responseZero = Gson().fromJson(textConflictZeroResponse, ApiResponse::class.java)
```

Then you can check the type of the response by doing:

```kotlin
if (responseOne.success is Boolean){
            Log.v(TAG,"Boolean")
        } else{
            Log.v(TAG,"not boolean")
        }
```